# Could phrasing the adultery law question better have saved it from being closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

The question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/whats-required-to-avoid-being-charged-with-adultery-in-south-korea , asking about anti-adultery laws and their application in South Korea, was closed as off-topic.

One of the close voters [wasn't sure](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/whats-required-to-avoid-being-charged-with-adultery-in-south-korea#comment9295_7172) whether it was a travel question, while [two](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/whats-required-to-avoid-being-charged-with-adultery-in-south-korea#comment9293_7172) [others](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/whats-required-to-avoid-being-charged-with-adultery-in-south-korea#comment9303_7172) either voiced some sort of moral objection, or, in my opinion, hinted at it. I'm not saying that that's the sole reason they closed the question, but it seems to have influenced their decision at least in part.

Could phrasing the question better have prevented it from getting the requisite close votes, especially from those who had a moral objection to the question?

Comment: avoid being charged with adultery, mixed gender onsen, dating tips... eating food which was refused by border protection.. I like your questions, seriously. It shows that you just ask whats in your mind without trying to make it look better to people who might get it wrong.. people like me I mean!..

Comment: @HaLaBi if you really like my questions, why did you vote to close one of them? Otherwise, if you do have a problem with one my questions, then provide constructive feedback rather than mockery.

Comment: I am not mocking, I told you I seriously like your questions, and that does not mean I can not dislike one of them. In my opinion and I will be honest your questions sound weird sometimes but that's one of the reasons why I like your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've flagged me as the one who said I wasn't sure about it being travel-specific, I should point out that I did NOT vote to close; as I said, I wasn't sure.  You can see the names of those who voted on the question.

Sure, subjectively, rephrasing may have saved it from being closed.  Just like any question could.  But it comes down to a community, and the final close reason was cited as 'off-topic' - so enough of the community believed strongly that it wasn't travel specific.

Really IMHO as it stands it's almost more of a legal question - change adultery to murder and you can see what I mean - in the title at least.  So yes, rewording may have helped.  Possibly some may have found it offensive, but you'd have to ask them individually :)

Comment: Apologies for misidentifying you that way.

Comment: Hey, we learn :)